# asp.net sitemap, can I have invisible nodes?

Tags: asp.net

I have a sitemap file with a 2 items

```
<siteMapNode url="/admin/products/default.aspx" title="Products">
 <siteMapNode url="/admin/products/add.aspx" title="Add" />
</siteMapNode>
```

However I also have an /admin/products/edit.aspx page. I want the Products sitemap node to be "selected" when I navigate to edit.aspx, as I am editing a Product, but I don't want Edit to appear in the menu. If the product menu remains unselected then there is no visible identifier that the user is still in that node.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I avoid the option altogether. I normally just eliminate the drop down and have my Products item navigate to a page that contains a list of my products (I paginate it so that only a few items appear on the page and not all of it). The page has an "Add" button on it, and the list contains buttons for View/Edit/Delete.
This page would be my `/admin/products/default.aspx`

If you'd rather not do it like this, then the only way I can think would be to manually populate the menu items.